# I changed the driver and now i cant boot anymore

Tags: boot

I changed the driver on my Ubuntu 23.04 .

Yes i went to additional drivers -> additional drivers -> and there I choosed the second option instead of default first option.

did this because I need to do this to connect my second monitor to my laptop.

Now it started to freeze so I rebooted and now I can't boot anymore.

I tried going in secure mode and repairing the packages but not solved.

I think I need to change the driver setting again somehow

I have a bootable usb

Comment: I run Ubuntu 23.04. Yes i went to additional drivers -> additional drivers -> and there I choosed the second option instead of default first option.

Comment: Tried with an previous version as well (from GRUB menu)?

Comment: Thanks!!! I tried the second option and it worked !